# Homework Help: Probability of 5 element subset having one prime and a single digit

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Here's the question:
Determine the probability that a randomly chosen 5-element subset of numbers from 1 to 20 contains at least one single digit number and at least one prime number.

Hi. Currently stuck on this homework problem. I also want to clarify with this that the prime number can also be a single digit number, so (3, 10, 11, 12, 13) should be a valid combination.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, the total number of 5-element subsets is given by `20*19*18*17*16 = 1,860480`
Then the number of subsets with single-digit prime numbers are `372,096 (4*19*18*17*16)` and the number of double digit prime numbers with an additional single digit is `176, 256 (4*9*18*17*16)`. If you combine these together, `(372,096 + 176, 256) / 1860480` then you get roughly 29%. However apparently this is wrong and should be around 90%

Comment: The number of 5-element subsets is $\binom{20}{5}=15504$ Are you familiar with the principle of inclusion/exclusion?

Comment: Heard of it, but not too sure about how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we find the number of unrestricted 5-element subsets to be $\binom{20}{5}=15504$ That is $\frac{20!}{5!(20-5)!}=\frac{20*19*18*17*16}{5*4*3*2*1}$

We need the number of subsets that do not contain a prime number. There are $8$ prime numbers in the set, so that leaves $12$ that are not prime. There are $\binom{12}{5}=792$ subsets that do not contain a prime number.

We need the number of subsets that do not contain a single-digit number. There are $9$ single-digit numbers in the set, so that leaves $11$ to choose from. There are $\binom{11}{5}=462$ subsets that do not contain a single-digit number.

We need the number of subsets that contain neither prime numbers nor single-digit numbers. There are $7$ numbers to choose from, so there are $\binom{7}{5}=21$ such subsets.

Now that we have these numbers, we can use inclusion/exclusion. We will start with the total number of subsets $(15504)$, exclude those that do not contain a prime number $(792)$ and those that do not contain a single-digit number $(462)$, then include those that do not contain either $(21)$ because they were excluded twice. This gives us our total of $$15504-792-462+21=14271$$ qualifying subsets.

The probability that on of these is randomly chosen is:
$$\frac{14271}{15504}\approx 92.05\%$$